# What's this electrical component symbol on a motor control circuit?

Tags: schematics, components

learning schematics (europe) what is this component called, why is it there and why is it connected to U? Motor can go reverse as well if that's relevant.

[image]

Comment: At a *guess*, it looks like how I might draw a solenoid-actuated brake on the motor.

Comment: A 1.5 kW brake solenoid seems unlikely, @Hearth, but I don't have better ideas just now.

Comment: @Transistor The 1.5 kW probably applies to the motor; it seems to go with "4p" and "I:3,5A" which are definitely motor specs. I expect whoever drew the diagram (or whoever made the symbol for the software in which the diagram was drawn) conceptualized the motor and its associated brake as a single unit.

Comment: yes, the 1.5kw 3.5amp applies to the motor, not the symbol on the left side of the motor

Answer (score 2):

According to [Radica Software](https://symbols.radicasoftware.com/225/iec-symbols) that's an electric brake as suggested by @Hearth.

[image]

1.5 kW seems rather high-powered for such a small motor.

Comment: ok good but how can it possibly be permanently connected to first phase "U" then? If that's the case, then it would simply try to brake the motor whenever it was energized.

For clarification, it's connected to first phase "U" then output goes to neutral.

Comment: Energise to release. That way it fails with brake applied.

Comment: Yes, the pressure plate is spring loaded. The solenoid unloads it.